# ASP.Net Core MVC SelectList not returning selected value to controller

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc

For some reason all the selectlists are returning 0 to my controller. Below is my code, can someone please help?

View:

```
<div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-12">
        <select app-for="customer.JobStage_Id" 
                asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.jobStages, "Id", "Description",customer.JobStage_Id))"  
                class="selectpicker  col-offset-1"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Populate the list:

```
public IEnumerable<Lookups> getJobStages()
{
    List<Lookups> jobStages = context.Lookups
                                     .Where(s => s.Lookup_Type_Id == 15).ToList();

    jobStages.Add(new Lookups { Id = 0, Description = "" });
    return jobStages;
}
```

This is the view source code and everything looks correct so I don't understand why my model in my action has zeros for all selectlists.

```html
                    <div class="row align-items-start">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <select app-for="customer.JobStatus_Id" class="selectpicker col-offset-1"><option value="40">Dormant</option>
<option value="41">Waiting For POB POA Flex</option>
<option value="42">Sent Flex to Council / Awaiting Invoice</option>
<option value="43">Waiting for EST</option>
<option value="44">Waiting for Flex to be sent to Council</option>
<option value="45">Sent for Data Match</option>
<option value="46">Other</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
</select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Below is my full view followed by the full action:

```html
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (customer.PK_Id == 0)
                {
                    customerRepository.add(customer);
                }
                else
                {
                    customerRepository.update(customer);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole action and view pls?

Comment: Please notice that your code is `<select app-for="customer.JobStatus_Id"`,it should be `asp-for`,not app.

Comment: Yinqiu thank you very much that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code.

In your action:

```
 public IActionResult ViewAction()
{         
    ViewData["JobStage_Id"] = new SelectList( context.Lookups.Where(s => s.Lookup_Type_Id == 15).ToList(), "Id", "Description");
    return View();
}
```

In your view:

```
 <select asp-for="customer.JobStage_Id" asp-items="ViewBag.JobStage_Id" class="selectpicker col-offset-1">
 </select>
```

***Please notice that your code is <select app-for="customer.JobStatus_Id",it should be asp-for,not app.***

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't help. I need to show the description of the job stages and return the Id. I have attached the view source and everything looks correct.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is even though I select a job stage in the drop down when I view source it still says the zero item is selected? Any ideas please?

Comment: You can see my comment.